# Ember CLI and import ... as

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

Using the following code in ember CLI works:

```
import X from 'source';
X.doSomething();
```

However, using an alternate form:

```
import {X as Y} from 'source';
Y.doSomething();
```

the browser logs an exception:

```
TypeError: Y is not defined
```

According to the [ES6 specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) this should work.  Is this behaviour just a limitation of Ember CLI, or is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you're using the wrong import syntax. The first code snippet you have is importing a default export, while the second one is using a named export. Take a look at the code below:

```
// This
import X from 'source';
// is to this
import Y from 'source';
// as this
import { X } from 'source';
// is to this
import { X as Y } from 'source';
```

In your case, you should be using the second form since you have a default export. You can also do the following, but I recommend against it for readability's sake.

```
import { default as Y } from 'source';
```